# Java mailing with Java Mail api

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail api in my project to send mail.But when i write code to attach file with mail,it takes lot of time in sending mail.And 4 times out of 5 it gives connection timeout error.I can not find out specific reason for it.File data is about 400 to 500 KB
Here is the code

```
public static void sendMailTo(String receiverEmailID, String emailSubject,String emailBody,ArrayList<String> attachmentFilepath) throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException {

        Properties properties = new Properties();           
        properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.text", "text/plain");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");

        // Authentication For Sender.
        if (session == null)
            session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password"
                            );
                        }
                    });

        // This block process to send mail on particular UserID
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session); 
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(""));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(receiverEmailID));
        message.setSubject(emailSubject);
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
        messageBodyPart.setDisposition(Part.INLINE);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
        int i=0;
        while(i<attachmentFilepath.size()){
              BodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
              DataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File(attachmentFilepath.get(i)));
              attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
              attachment.setFileName(source.getName());
              attachment.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
              multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);              
              i++;
        }    
        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(message);// This statement send Message.             
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to attach and how large is it?

Comment: Where is the code ? Why question is tagged with `php` tag ?

Comment: @epoch, sarcastic, not helpful ;)

Comment: Anyway, use Commons Email to avoid problems : http://commons.apache.org/email/

Comment: @epoch I could have sworn they were gold. Must be a trick of the light. Or the LSD flakes I had for breakfast.

Answer (score 0):

try **ping smtp.gmail.com -t**

Do you have lost packages? If yes this is the answer to your problem (network problems)